# How to refer to files that were added via the data_files attribute?

Tags: py2app

With py2app, say I added several files to my package using this:

```
DATA_FILES = [
    ('images', ['images/picture.jpg', 'images/picture2.png']),
    ('images/icons', ['images/icons/ico1.ico'])
]
```

and in my original I used to access these files using `'./images/picture.jpg'` for example. How should I refer to them now?

I've tried both using the same path and using `./Contents/Resources//images/picture.jpg` but neither work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, paths obtained via `os.getcwd()` refer to `./Contents/Resources/` after running py2app on my machine.

To better understand your exact problem, run the executable file in `*.app/Contents/MacOS/`, then copy and share the traceback error message that comes up in your Terminal console. Also, try to insert print statements to analyse your paths in Terminal.